# angular Error: $parse:ueoe Unexpected End of Expression for a couple of expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following two expressions are throwing the error:

```
ng-click="vm.numOthersAttending++"
ng-click="vm.numOthersAttending = vm.numOthersAttending > 0 ? vm.numOthersAttending - 1 : 0"
```

Can't I just put any expression in an ngClick for evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-click="vm.numOthersAttending = vm.numOthersAttending + 1">click</div>
<div ng-click="vm.numOthersAttending = (vm.numOthersAttending > 0) ? (vm.numOthersAttending - 1) : 0">click</div>
```

In general it is better to use functions.

Comment: hmm, can you expand on this? I tend to stay away from functions for these kind of one liners because it clutters the controller.

Answer (score 1):

> Can't I just put any expression in an ngClick for evaluation?

Not any expression. You can put an *angular expression*, i.e. an expression according to [this guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> - Context: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.
> - Forgiving: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.
> - No Control Flow Statements: You cannot use the following in an Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
> - No Function Declarations: You cannot declare functions in an Angular expression, even inside ng-init directive.
> - No RegExp Creation With Literal Notation: You cannot create regular expressions in an Angular expression.
> - No Comma And Void Operators: You cannot use , or void in an Angular expression.
> - Filters: You can use filters within expressions to format data before displaying it.

You cannot use control flow, but you can use ternary operator.

Your error comes from that part `ng-click="numOthersAttending++"`. This is not supported.